# "request" at the deform validation

Tags: python, pyramid, deform

i need the "request" for this custom validation in deform to work:

```
def d_validator(node, value):
    if not value:
        raise Invalid(node, 'Enter a Password')
    if len(value) < 5:
        raise Invalid(node, 'Invalid Length')
    userid = authenticated_userid(userrequest)
    dbsession = DBSession()
    userInfo = dbsession.query(User).filter(_and(User.id==userid, User.password == value)).first()
    if not userInfo:
        raise Invalid(node, 'Invalid password')
```

so i tried this:

```
class Form(field.Field):
    def __init__(self, schema, **kw):
        self.saved_user = kw.pop('userrequest')
        log.info(self.saved_user)
        super(Form, self).__init__(schema, **kw)
```

and then:

```
Form(schema, buttons=('Actualizar',), 'userrequest'=request)
```

but i get SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

i know this could be python related, bear with me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords are indeed not expressions, but `'userrequest'=request` *is*. Remove the quotes:

```
Form(schema, buttons=('Actualizar',), userrequest=request)
```

Also, why are you basing your custom `Form` class on `field.Field`? I haven't used deform yet myself, but from a quick glance at the [documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/) suggest *strongly* you should be inheriting from `deform.Form` instead.

Last but not least, you *could* fall back to the [pyramid thread-local request](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/threadlocal.html#pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_request) instead:

```
def d_validator(node, value):
    if not value:
        raise Invalid(node, 'Enter a Password')
    if len(value) < 5:
        raise Invalid(node, 'Invalid Length')
    userid = authenticated_userid(get_current_request())
    dbsession = DBSession()
    userInfo = dbsession.query(User).filter(_and(User.id==userid, User.password == value)).first()
    if not userInfo:
        raise Invalid(node, 'Invalid password')
```

Yes, this is often frowned upon, but could be easier in your case to deal with.

Comment: thanks that was one of my problems, but not sure how to override the Form class, now its not showing me the submit button, maybe could help me out?

Comment: Yes i changed it later for Form but got problems accesing the self, or the variable in that context. I am new to python and this python web development, comming from php, anyways i ended doing it with the get_current_request solution and works fine. Later with some time i will try a better way. Thanks.